# C#/C++ - Memory Leak

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I have a C++ DLL (**no source code / .pdb available for C++ DLL**) in production. It is being called by a C# application using P/Invoke mechanism. Now, there is a leak in the C++ DLL. And, after executing for 20-22 times, the application crashes everytime. Now, how can I gracefully handle this such that I continue to use the C++ DLL with the leak from C# App?

Comment: You don't want to find the root cause of the leak and fix it, but just be graceful? I must admit that this is a strange attitude towards bugs in your software.

Comment: Can you provide the interop definitions for C++ DLL.

Comment: I do not have the source. I know its strange !

Comment: @Darin: How would you suggest fixing a DLL for which source code isn't available?

Comment: are you sure the problem is memory leak ?

Comment: @Ben Voigt, for example by throwing away the crap and acquiring/writing something that works and doesn't leak memory. Seems reasonable, isn't it? At least that's what I would do if I discovered that the a library I am using is leaking and I don't have the source code for it.

Comment: @Felice - Yes, have checked with counters and profilers

Comment: @Darin: Whether that's reasonable depends on how many people are capable of reimplementing it.  It might be cheaper to just wrap it in a separate process which gets recycled occasionally.  Not my preferred choice, but sometimes fixing it right isn't feasible.

Comment: Not only is you approach to solving this rather weak (you should be lancing the boil not covering it in make up), but it seems rather hard to believe that a memory leak results in a crash after 20 calls. Are you really sure? If so then what is the mechanism whereby a memory leak in native code brings down your managed app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to me, if it is absolutely impssible to modify / replace the c++ dll, and you are sure there is no problem in the PInvoke layer, the only option iif the performance remain acceptable, is to *insulate* the dll call in an executable communicating with the main one with some IPC ( Remoting for example ) so you can force recycling in the hosting process. This approach would work only if the way you call the c++ dll is not too granular. A way to do this with as less effort as possible is to crete a **web service** hosting the C++ call ( if calling the C++ as a web service is feasible always in term of performance ), host it in a special appdomain and specify for it a reciclying based on memory amount. If this is not possible, the solution propsed by SeeSharp in his comment below is probably the best one.

Comment: +1, I wanted to suggest almost the same, you have been 30 seconds quicker than me

Comment: Looks feasible. Can I create process, call C++ DLL and then say, after 20 calls, kill the process and then spawn a new one and then call again ?

Comment: @SeeSharp I'm going to extend the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the interop, I would suggest that the C++ is returning a structure/class that you must free.

Comment: Leak is inside a function. C# layer cannot do anything.

Comment: How do you know this.  Can you provide the interop to C++ function(s)

Answer (score 0):

Run the C++ code in a separate process, that way when the memory leak accumulates to an unacceptable level, you can restart it without affecting the rest of your application.

Comment: Yes, agreed. See the detailed reply from @Felice too. Its similar to what you are saying. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

- <strike>You may want to isolate your calls to this function in a custom [`AppDomain`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx). Unload/recreate the `AppDomain` from time to time (or maybe each time).</strike> *Unmanaged DLLs are not unloaded with AppDomains*
- You could wrap your library in an out of process COM component ([example here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/977996)). You could then [release](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.finalreleasecomobject.aspx)/recreate this component at will.
- You may also want to work in a place where they don't throw their source code away...